# Problem with automatically booting

Tags: boot, grub2

After upgrade from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 I am unable to get Ubuntu to automatically boot. Even when I set grub.cfg as follows:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

when rebooting, GRUB waits on its splash screen for keypressing on selected kernel.

Please help if you have any idea. I updated a grub by `update-grub` command with different timeout but it does not change.

Comment: Did you edit `grub.cfg` or `/etc/default/grub` file. I think, it is the later one

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit /etc/default/grub not grub.cfg. Change it from there and run

```
sudo update-grub2
```